# Command button to open report subject to criteria selected in combobox

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form [Supervisors] with 2 comboboxes: supervisor, position.

I have a report for employees with all kinds of information, among which are supervisor and position.  I want to make a command button that opens the report subject to whichever supervisor and position are chosen within the comboboxes.  This should be as simple as limiting in the WHERE statement, correct?  I used the Expression Builder to say:

```
Where Condition = [position] Like [Forms]![Supervisors]![PositionCombo]
                   AND [sup] Like [Forms]![Supervisors]![SupervisorCombo]
```

Yet when I click the button I get "The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize '[Forms]![Supervisors]![PositionCombo]' as a valid field name or expression."  How do I tell Access to use the combobox values as limiting criteria?

I don't know VBA, though I do plan to learn.  If possible, I would like to accomplish this without needing VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [OpenReport Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238032%28v=office.12%29.aspx) *WhereCondition* option to filter the report's record source based on your combo box values.

```vb
Dim strWhereCondition As String
strWhereCondition = "[position] = " & Me.[PositionCombo].Value _
    & " AND [sup] = " & Me.[SupervisorCombo].Value
Debug.Print strWhereCondition
DoCmd.OpenReport "Your Report", View:=acViewPreview, _
    WhereCondition:=strWhereCondition
```

I assumed numeric data types for `[position]` and `[sup]`.  If they are actually text instead, quote the values in *strWhereCondition*.

```vb
strWhereCondition = "[position] = '" & Me.[PositionCombo].Value _
    & "' AND [sup] = '" & Me.[SupervisorCombo].Value & "'"
```